# For Loop produces extra 1 with List<> Enumerable.Range()

Tags: c#, list, loops, for-loop

I have 2 Lists, `letter` and `indexLetter`, each with 50 variables, starting at `1` instead of `0`.

I need to have both lists as seperate collections.

---

I generate a random letter and add it to the `letter` List:

```
W
G
I
Y
H
...
```

Then combine it with its index number and add it to the `indexLetter` List:

```
W1
G2
I3
Y4
H5
...
```

However my code outputs an extra `1` at the beginning:

```
1
W1
G2
I3
Y4
H5
...
```

---

**C#**

http://rextester.com/SINT13872

```
// Letter List
public static List<char> letter = Enumerable.Range(1, 51)
                                            .Select(i => '\0') // null char
                                            .ToList();
// Index Number List
public static List<string> indexLetter = Enumerable.Range(1, 51)
                                            .Select(i => i.ToString()) // number
                                            .ToList();
// Generate Random Letter
public static Random random = new Random();
public static char RandomLetter()
{
    const string text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int index = random.Next(text.Length);
    return text[index];
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // Combine Random Letter with Index Number
    for (var i = 1; i < 51; i++)
    {
        // Letter
        letter[i] = RandomLetter();

        // Letter + Index Number
        indexLetter[i] = letter[i] + i.ToString();
    }

   // Display Letter + Index Letter List
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", indexLetter));
}
```

---

Another example removing the extra `1` but producing an empty Letter.

http://rextester.com/CEQN38224

```
1
V2
N3
Y4
V5
```

Comment: Cause of problem: You're starting your for loop from 1 rather than 0. Indexes start at 0.

Comment: You seem to think `Enumerable.Range(1, 51).ToList()` creates a list with 50 elements starting with 1 at index 1 but it actually creates a list with 51 elements starting with 1 at index 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set `indexLetter[0]`, so it is left at `'\0'`, which ends up being the initial character of the result. Fix this by skipping the first item of `indexLetter`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", indexLetter.Skip(1)));
```

Note that you can fold the whole operation into a single LINQ expression:

```
public static List<string> indexLetter = Enumerable.Range(1, 50)
    .Select(i => string.Format("{0}{1}", RandomLetter(), i))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: He's creating the list "indexLetter" beforehand, and it contains 51 items. If you skip one, it leaves out item number 1. He can get the correct result by simply changing his for loop to start at 0.

Comment: http://rextester.com/OZUP85263 It seems to work. Also another problem was `.Select(i => i.ToString())` needed to be `string.Empty` to not produce the `1`.

Comment: @john OP is careful to not use index zero at all. I tried this one change, and it fixes the problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'd argue that that's still not the correct solution, but I'll upvote because I like the single Linq expression. Now that is probably the right solution. Except the second variable in Range is Count, so if he wants 50 items it should be 50, not 51.

Answer (score 2):

Change how you generate your lists:

```
// Letter List
public static List<char> letter = Enumerable.Range(1, 50)
                                        .Select(i => '\0') // null char
                                        .ToList();
// Index Number List
public static List<string> indexLetter = Enumerable.Range(1, 50)
                                        .Select(i => i.ToString()) // number
                                        .ToList();
```

This will produce two lists with 50 items from 1-50.

Next, change your for loop like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < indexLetter.Count; i++)
{
    // Letter
    letter[i] = RandomLetter();

    // Letter + Index Number
    indexLetter[i] = letter[i] + indexLetter[i];
}
```

[Fiddle](http://rextester.com/UNUZ36026)

Comment: Here is what it is doing. It's showing 0-49. http://rextester.com/RLRJ98783

Comment: @Matt I have fixed my answer. Your original fiddle didn't marry up with the code you posted in your question, and I made the mistake of assuming they were the same. In your question you have `i.ToString()` and in your fiddle (on rextester) you have `indexLetter[i]`. I made my change recommendations based on the fiddle, hence the difference. I've fixed my fiddle link, too.

Comment: Frankly, just use dasblinkenlight's Linq method. It makes more sense than what you're currently doing and it's easier to understand/read.